# SharePoint migration - External List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, migration, external-list

I am doing a migration (mostly content) from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint Online. There are a couple of External lists spread across the site collections.

Any ideas/recommendations on how I should approach this scenario -> is there an alternative in SharePoint Online to have those Lists implemented? BCS maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If data is present in External list you can try to connect SharePoint online to an on Premises SQL server using Azure Provider hosted app and hybrid connections .

But for this need to make sure that external list has data in form of database tables .

Answer (score 1):

As yash's reply, there are two methods to connect SharePoint Online to on-premises SQL Server:

**1. Create an Azure provider hosted app using Hybrid Connections.**

**2. Create a WCF service which is run on-premises alongside the DB and then interact with the on-premises data**

Articles:

[Connect SharePoint Online and SQL Server On-Premises with BCS/SharePoint Apps using Hybrid Connection and WCF Services](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/11/13/connect-sharepoint-online-and-sql-server-on-premises-with-bcs-sharepoint-apps-using-hybrid-connection-and-wcf-services/)

[How to: Create a Basic WCF Web HTTP Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service)

Or we can also migrate the external list from on-premise database to SQL Azure, then use the BCS to achieve it.

[Make an External List from a SQL Azure table with Business Connectivity Services and Secure Store](http://Make%20an%20External%20List%20from%20a%20SQL%20Azure%20table%20with%20Business%20Connectivity%20Services%20and%20Secure%20Store)